# How to use webjars with grails and the asset-pipeline

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, compass, webjars

I'm trying to use sass-asset-pipeline:2.9.4 which uses libsass instead of compass.  However a lot of my .scss files use mixins not available in libsass, so I found a webjar, compass-mixin, that has the mixins I want.

The asset-pipeline doesn't find the mixins though, I get a `ERROR asset.pipeline.jsass.SassAssetFileImporter - Unable to find the asset for compass imported by home.scss` error message when it tries to rune `@import "compass";`.

I've tried various path in the import as the asset-pipeline says that it works with webjars.

How do I get the `@import "compass";` to work?

Answer (score 1):

Example of the solution I ended up with:

in build.gradle

```
assets 'org.webjars.bower:compass-mixins:1.0.2'

bootRun {
    dependsOn 'webjars resources extraction'
    systemProperties = System.properties
}

task('webjars resources extraction', type: Copy) {
    def jar = configurations.runtime.filter { it.name.contains('compass-mixins') }.first()

    copy {
        from zipTree(jar)
        into "./grails-app/assets/stylesheets/vendor"
        include 'META-INF/resources/webjars/compass-mixins/1.0.2/lib/**'
    }

    copy {
        from "./grails-app/assets/stylesheets/vendor/META-INF/resources/webjars/compass-mixins/1.0.2/lib"
        into "./grails-app/assets/stylesheets/vendor"
    }
    delete "grails-app/assets/stylesheets/vendor/META-INF"
}

assetClean {
    delete 'grails-app/assets/stylesheets/vendor'
}
```

I also had to change the imports in my .scss file to:

```
@import "vendor/compass";
@import "vendor/compass/css3";
```

@Jeremy POUILLOT: your solution is seems like less work, although I note that the plugin says it is no longer in active development, and it needs jruby on the path.

Answer (score 0):

edit: stupid answer from myself, didn't work at all, sorry for that.

Still searching how to make compass works with grails/sass

Comment: I ended up copying the files into a assets/stylesheets/vendor folder under the grails-app with a gradle task.

Comment: Does it work with the latest `sass-asset-pipeline:2.9.4`?